# How old is Kevin Uxbridge?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In "The Survivors," we're introduced to an enigmatic and powerful being known as a Douwd. In human form, he goes by the name Kevin Uxbridge. He states that he's lived in the system for thousands of years, but is it possible to know his overall age? Perhaps from a source outside of the episode itself?

[image: shot of a man's face, he wears a yellow shirt and has short, white curly hair]

Answer (score 2):

Kevin is the only Dowud we know of and, to the best of my knowledge, never appears in any other episode or in any lesser-canon work. We have nothing to go on but his word.

Comment: This is more appropriate as a comment. Also, I take statements in Star Trek to be true, unless there are good reasons to doubt them. Otherwise, you can doubt everything.

Comment: What's wrong with 'We don't know' as an answer in a case where we don't know? Additionally, since KU spent the first half of the episode *lying*, I'm not sure I agree that we can give him the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: "We don't know" by itself is an acceptable answer but a lousy one. Some more info would be helpful.

Comment: It's like when Data asks whether a lack of dimension is a dimension in of itself. Frankly, I think that answers should be fleshed out, not merely say "beats me." Kevin wasn't exactly upfront, but I'm not sure I'd say that he was blatantly lying. I could be forgetting an example of him blatantly lying, though. In a one-time character/plot situation like this, I think viewers are expected to take "final" statements as being valid. I really doubt that the writers intended this to be a mystery plot that would never be resolved. It's resolved at the end when Kevin spills his guts.

Comment: A brief list of lines in which Kevin is lying:
KEVIN: We don't know. [who attacked them]
KEVIN: We've told you time and time again, we don't know why we were spared. 
KEVIN: I expected to die like all the others.
KEVIN: I will not kill. 
Kevin also says that "...I am a Douwd. An immortal being of disguises and false surroundings..." and "until today, no one has known my true identity". His entire multi-millenial existence, he has been living undiscovered lies. What's more a liar's trademark than saying "Oh, got me, I was lying, but that was the /only/ thing I was lying about, I swear."